# Personal belonging/s storage

Tags: nouns

Let's say you're promoting a hotel. And you say:

> "We have many bedrooms, and each bedroom can even accommodate 3 people without having any problem for their personal **belonging/belongings** storage."

Is it **belonging** or **belongings?**

Comment: Use the plural form in this case

Comment: Personal *belongings*, but *"can even accommodate three people without any problems storing their personal belongings"* sounds better.